# Loop through table and return a specific column

Tags: postgresql, loops, types, plpgsql, identifier

Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getAllFoo()
  RETURNS SETOF "TraderMonthOutstanding" AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r  record;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN (select * from "TraderMonthOutstanding"
              where "TraderId"=1 and "IsPaid"=false)
    LOOP

    RETURN NEXT r.TraderId; 

    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

I want only `TraderId` from this loop but I am not able to get it because it gives me an error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And the error is? (btw: you don't need a loop. A simple `return query` or a plain SQL function would be totally enough)

Comment: It is an only fraction of a actual query....

Comment: if it's only a single query, there is no need for a loop (and it will be *much* faster without it) - and you still haven't told us the error message

Answer (score 1):

You declared that `getAllFoo()` will `RETURNS SETOF "TraderMonthOutstanding"` (a set of rows with structure of table `TraderMonthOutstanding`) but then you `RETURN NEXT r.TraderId` (single field).

You need to either change the declared return type to `RETURNS SETOF "TraderMonthOutstanding".TraderId%TYPE` or `RETURN NEXT r`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be returning a `setof integer`, or a `setof TraderMonthOutstanding".TraderId%TYPE`.

Or changing perhaps a `setof record` and returning `next r`, or event `setof TraderMonthOutstanding` and declaring r as a TraderMonthOutstanding row type instead of an anonymous record.

Better yet, this seems like the kind of case where you ought to create a view to avoid the overhead of the using a function altogether:

```
create view getAllFoo as
select *
from "TraderMonthOutstanding"
where "TraderId"=1 and "IsPaid"=false;

select * from getAllFoo;
```

It's usually terrible practice to loop over a set like that in a function if you're not doing anything useful. (Though I imagine the real one is doing *something*.)

Lastly, in the event you truly want this in a function, note that you can `return query` to avoid the loop altogether:

```
return query
select *
from "TraderMonthOutstanding"
where "TraderId"=1 and "IsPaid"=false;
```

Answer (score 1):

What @Igor and @Denis said.
If you actually *need* the loop, which doesn't become apparent from your example, it would work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_foo()
  RETURNS SETOF "TraderMonthOutstanding"."TraderId"%TYPE AS
$func$
DECLARE
   r  "TraderMonthOutstanding";  -- use the well known type
BEGIN
   FOR r IN
      SELECT * FROM "TraderMonthOutstanding"
      WHERE  "TraderId" = 1
      AND    "IsPaid" = FALSE    -- no parentheses needed
   LOOP
      -- do whatever necessitates a loop
      RETURN NEXT r."TraderId";
   END LOOP;

   RETURN;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- Do not quote the language name `plpgsql`. It's an identifier, not a literal. Current Postgres tolerates it, but it may be weeded out in future versions.
- I would advice not to use CaMeL-case identifiers *at all* in Postgres. Even less if you double-quote some, but not others. That's a LoaDed Footgun. [Read the manual about identifiers.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)
- Since you already *know* the type of the record you are going to use, don't downgrade to an anonymous `record`, use the well known type to begin with: "TraderMonthOutstanding".
- Like you have been told already, the type returned by `RETURN` has to match what you declared with `RETURNS`. Since you `want only TraderId`, adapt `RETURNS` accordingly. If you want to derive it from the existing table you can use the syntax displayed. [Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) Or you can insert the actual type. Like `integer` or whatever.
- And since you seem to have been using double-quoted CaMeL-case names when creating your table, you have to keep using them that way: **double-quoted** - even for fields of the derived type in the function body:

  ```
  RETURN NEXT r."TraderId";
  ```

See what I mean with "LoaDed Footgun"?